# cucumber table with valid and invalid input

Tags: cucumber, numberformatexception, invalid-argument

I have that kind of test which works:

```
Feature: TestAddition

  Scenario Outline: "Addition"
    Given A is <A> and B is <B>
    Then A + B is <result>

    Examples: 
      | A      | B    | result |
      |      3 |    4 |      7 |
      |      2 |    5 |      7 |
      |      1 |    4 |      5 |
```

And thats the glue code:

```
package featuresAdditions;

import org.junit.Assert;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import math.AdditionEngine;

public class step {

    private AdditionEngine testAdditionEngine;
    private double resultAddition;

    @Given("^A is (\\d+) and B is (\\d+)$")
    public void addition(int arg1, int arg2) throws Throwable {
        testAdditionEngine = new AdditionEngine();
        resultAddition = testAdditionEngine.calculateAdditionAmount(arg1, arg2);
        }


    @Then("^A + B is (.)$")
    public void addition(double arg1) throws Throwable {
        Assert.assertEquals(arg1, resultAddition, 0.01);
    }      
}
```

However I would like to know how to create an invalid table example [where ?? means I do not know what to put in the below table]

```
Examples: 
  | A      | B    | result |
  | "é3-3" |    5 |     ?? |
  | "é3-3" | "aB" |     ?? |
```

This should give a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`

In pure jUnit I would do something like the code below which works like a charm [with   `@Test(expected = NumberFormatException.class)`]. However, I have to use Cucumber... Someone can tell me how to perform such a test with Cucubmer?

```
public class test {
    AdditionEngine testAdditionEngine = new AdditionEngine();
    @Test(expected = NumberFormatException.class)
    public void test() {
        testAdditionEngine.calculateAdditionAmount("é3-3", 5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  Scenario Outline: "Invalid Addition"
    Given A is <A> and B is <B>
    Then A + B is <result>

    Examples: 
      | A      | B    | result                          |
      | "é3-3" | 5    | java.lang.NumberFormatException |
      | "é3-3" | "aB" | java.lang.NumberFormatException |
```

Change the stepdefinition to take a `String` as an argument instead of `Integer`.

```
private Exception excep;

    @Given("^A is (.*?) and B is (.*?)$")
    public void addValid(String arg1, String arg2) {

        try {
            testAdditionEngine = new AdditionEngine();
            testAdditionEngine.calculateAdditionAmount(arg1, arg2);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            excep = e;
        }
    };

    @Then("^A \\+ B is (.*?)$")
    public void validResult(String arg1){
        assertEquals(arg1, excep.getClass().getName());
    };
```

You will get an ambiguous step message if you are on Cucumber 2 and above. This will be because the valid scenariooutline will match the integer and string stepdefinitions. Change either one of the scenario statements.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello I tried but on the cucumber HTML. report I got a "java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String" and the test is shown as red [instead of green]. If I do addValid(String arg1, String arg2) I get a varning saying  "method ... not applicable for the arguments (String, String)" ... What should I do ? I cannot change the type of calculateAdditionAmount that would not make sense..

Comment: I run the test with the code i posted. Everything is fine. I am adding the console and report image. Change the scenario statement in the feature file for the invalid scenario. Something like -- Invalid A is <A> and Invalid B is <B>. Also for the second statement of result. Then you will need to create a separate stepdef code. Then you will have no conflict with valid cases

Comment: I still do not understand. The method calculateAdditionAmount is calculateAdditionAmount(int, int). So when I write addValid(String arg1, String arg2) it does not work. Thus, did you change the method calculateAdditionAmount to calculateAdditionAmount(String, String) ?